# how to show hidden button in listview for authorized user only?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

When a authorized person enter to watch group list, the listview don't contain delete option but if avalide person watch group list, listview will contain delete button(Like facebook group, admin will show some extra option but member will not)

here is my code

MemberActivity.java

```
public class MemberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListView memberListListView;

private String userIdString;
private String groupIdString;
private String groupNameString;
private String universityNameString;
MemberListAdapter memberListAdapter;


private SQLiteHandler db;
ArrayList<MemberLisModel> memberList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_member);

    memberListListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.memberListLV);

    userIdString = getIntent().getStringExtra("UserId");
    groupIdString = getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupId");
    groupNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupName");
    universityNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("UniversityName");



    db=new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    memberList=db.getMemberListFromGroupMemberList(groupIdString);
    if(memberList.size()!=0 && memberList.size()>0) {
        final MemberListAdapter memberListAdapter = new MemberListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, memberList);
        memberListListView.setAdapter(memberListAdapter);
    }

    boolean cr=db.chechCrStatus(userIdString,groupIdString);


}
```

}

MemberListAdapter.java

```
public class MemberListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MemberLisModel> {

TextView memberName;
TextView joiningDate;
TextView crIdentification;
public Button memberDeleteButton;


public MemberListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MemberLisModel> objects) {
    super(context, 0,objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    MemberLisModel memberLisModel=getItem(position);
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_member_view,parent,false);
    }
    memberName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meberNameTV);
    joiningDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberJoiningDateTV);
    crIdentification= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crIdentificationTV);
    memberDeleteButton= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberDeleteBtn);

    String memberStatus=memberLisModel.getMemberStatus();

    if (memberStatus.toLowerCase().equals("true")){
        crIdentification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    memberName.setText(memberLisModel.getMemberName());
    joiningDate.setText(memberLisModel.getMemberListCreatedAt());

    return  convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where is the problem ?

You got the code in adapter -

```
  if (memberStatus.toLowerCase().equals("true")) // is admin ?
  {   
        crIdentification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        memberDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
  else
  {
        memberDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
```